# 2d Arrays of type string in C++;

Tags: c++

Hello Everyone I am trying to implement 2d array with of size 5*5 and some strings in it.When i=I am trying to print the 2d array in loops its giving error on "<<" sign,I dont know how to resolve it can anyone help me with it.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string students[5][5]={"Wayne","Val","Yolanda","Zeus","Xavier",
                           "Yolanda","Wayne","Val","Xavier","Zeus",
                           "Wayne","Zeus","Xavier","Wayne","Zeus",
                           "Val","Yolanda","Xavier","Wayne","Zeus",
                           "Wayne","Yolanda","Val","Zeus","Xavier"};

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            cout<<students[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your initial values look like they are 1d, no?

Comment: You forgot `#include <string>`.

Comment: Although some system don't require it, you should add `#include <string>` to use `std::string`.

Comment: This is a common problem with MSVC. `<iostream>` provides `std::string` (which leads to forgetting `<string>`) but not `operator(ostream&, const std::string&)`.

Answer (score 3):

You should include string

```
#include <string>
```

then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   //<-------
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string students[5][5] = { 
        {"Wayne","Val","Yolanda","Zeus","Xavier"},
        {"Yolanda","Wayne","Val","Xavier","Zeus"},
        {"Wayne","Zeus","Xavier","Wayne" ,"Zeus"},
        {"Val","Yolanda","Xavier","Wayne","Zeus"},
        {"Wayne","Yolanda","Val","Zeus","Xavier"}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)

        {
            cout << students[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing a single array of length 25. You have to do the init like so:

```
  string students[5][5]={ { "Wayne","Val","Yolanda","Zeus","Xavier" },
                          { "Yolanda","Wayne","Val","Xavier","Zeus" },
                          { "Wayne","Zeus","Xavier","Wayne","Zeus" },
                          { "Val","Yolanda","Xavier","Wayne","Zeus" },
                          { "Wayne","Yolanda","Val","Zeus","Xavier" } };
```

And, as François Andrieux mentionned in the comments, you should also include the proper header

```
#include <string>
```

because it defines the `operator<<` for strings.

Comment: That's not necessary. You can initialize an array of array from a flat list of elements.